# delete excel worksheets programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have an excel workbook with many, many sheets. I want to delete all the sheets except for three of them.

Specifically, i would like to know if there is a way to remove the sheets using sheet name instead of ordinals (sheet number).

I am using excel interop and C# to work with Excel.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = null;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = null;
Excel.Sheets xlSheets = null;
Excel.Worksheet xlNewSheet = null;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
for (int i = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count; i > 0 ; i--)
{
    Worksheet wkSheet = (Worksheet)xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[i];
    if (wkSheet.Name == "NameOfSheetToDelete")
    {
        wkSheet.Delete();
    }
}
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
```

Comment: This is wrong, I believe. Shouldn't you be going downward in your loop instead, since you're deleting from within the collection of worksheets? `for (int i = WorkSheets.Count; i > 1; i--)`

Comment: No `C#` expert but `xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false` etc should reside outside the loop.

Comment: Per @KenWhite's comment, yes, you have to loop backwards on the delete, otherwise you will end up with an `i` that is out of bounds -- if you delete even *one* worksheet, you will never be able to reach `.Worksheets.Count` since by that time, that sheet index no longer exists in the `Sheets` collection.  Otherwise you could do a `For each wksheet` loop, and delete based on the sheet's `.Name`.

Comment: @KenWhite I changed the for-loop to decrement, but do note the code here only deletes one sheet so the direction of the loop doesn't matter. Same goes for the `xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false` its never called more than once so there is no real difference putting it outside the loop - but I did anyway...

Comment: @JeremyThompson  it is called more than once. `I want to delete **all** the sheets except for three of them`

Comment: @brettdj I saw that but I thought the real question was "specifically" `if there is a way to remove the sheets using sheet name`. Cheers:)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I just use the fallowing

`workBook.Sheets["Sheet1"].Delete();`

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is really old but for future visitors, if you know the names of the sheets you want to delete, a better way is to loop over the names of the sheets like this:

```
Workbook book = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("filePathHere");
string[] sheetsToDelete = {"s1", "s2"};
excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false; 
foreach(string sheetToDelete in sheetsToDelete )
{
    book.Worksheets[sheetToDelete].Delete();
}
excelApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
```

It's always good practice to avoid deleting items in a collection while iterating through it.

Comment: This is great advice.