# Why am I getting a superfluous sheet even though I'm explicitly setting sheet count to 1?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-interop, excel.application

I want to avoid generated spreadsheets having empty/superfluous sheets named "Sheet1" and such. I thought I could do that by specifying how many sheets a workbook should have this way:

```
_xlApp = new Excel.Application { SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1 };
```

...But I'm still getting an unwanted "Sheet1" in addition to the sheet I create. Here is the pertinent code:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
. . .
private Excel.Application _xlApp;
private Excel.Workbook _xlBook;
private Excel.Sheets _xlSheets;
private Excel.Worksheet _xlSheet;
. . .
private void InitializeSheet()
{
    _xlApp = new Excel.Application { SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1 };
    _xlBook = _xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
    _xlBook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    _xlSheets = _xlBook.Worksheets;
    _xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)_xlSheets.Item[1];
    _xlSheet.Name = String.Format("Price Compliance {0} {1}", _month, _year);
}
```

So since setting SheetsInNewWorkbook to 1 in the Excel.Application instance doesn't do the trick, what do I need to do to prevent these tramp sheets from showing up?

Comment: Not sure about why it's adding the sheet, but maybe add a line that removes a sheet called "Sheet1" at the end, after you set up your sheet?

Comment: @Batman: How is that done? I have never removed a sheet.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not well versed (or even terribly versed) in C# for Excel.  However, it looks like [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328923/delete-excel-worksheets-programatically) has that answer to that question.  Does that help?

Comment: @Batman: Thanks, that link had two good ideas, the water pistol, which will probably work, and the water cannon, which I might use just for the heck of it.

Comment: @pnuts - if he changed that to `0` would it create a single sheet?  Since the default is 1, I'm thinking the number he has, `1`, technically means *in addition to default number*?

Comment: @BruceWayne The `SheetsInNewWorkbook` property must be between 1 and 255. But @B.ClayShannon, I'm confused because simply removing your line `_xlBook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);` would do the trick since you'd simply be renaming `Sheet1`

Comment: @test - you're right; that was a bogus call to Worksheets.Add(). Removing it solved the superfluency. Make that an answer, and I'll mark it as such.

Comment: @pnuts - I was thinking it'd be understood as `create 0 additional sheets to default amount`. But that's probably not right.  And it looks like B.ClayShannon found his solution anyways, so huzzah!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question can be found in the documentation of the `Template` parameter on the `Workbook.Add` method.

> [...] If this argument is omitted, Microsoft Excel creates a new
>   workbook with a number of blank sheets (the number of sheets is set by
>   the `SheetsInNewWorkbook` property).

Your code is omitting it, therefore it is creating a single Worksheet for you (since you've set `SheetsInNewWorkbook` to 1.

That property is also constrained to be between 1 and 255, so you aren't able to add a work book without a sheet (unless you use a file template).

Also from the `Template` parameter documentation:

> If this argument is a constant, the new workbook contains a **single**
>   **sheet** of the specified
>        type. Can be one of the following `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWBATemplate`
>        constants: `xlWBATChart`, `xlWBATExcel4IntlMacroSheet`, `xlWBATExcel4MacroSheet`,
>        or `xlWBATWorksheet`.

So an alternative way to do this is:

```
_xlApp = new Excel.Application();
_xlBook = _xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
_xlSheets = _xlBook.Worksheets;
_xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)_xlSheets.Item[1];
_xlSheet.Name = String.Format("Price Compliance {0} {1}", _month, _year);
```

Which simply renames the single created sheet.